# C++ coding with Enable/disable methods of WIN32_NetworkAdapter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, network-programming, wmi

I'm trying to enable/disable my network ethernet interface using C++ and WIN32_NetworkAdapter class of WMI. But unfortunately i did not found how the  methods of the class may be invoked.
thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! I'm a little bit unclear what you're asking here. Can you edit the post to explicitly state what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

To execute the WMI methods you must use the [`ExecMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of the [`IWbemServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. On this case you must pass the Index of the Network adapter to Enable/Disble methods.

Btw if you are new using the WMI and C++ you can use the [WDCC](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) Tool , which can help you generate code to access the WMI from C++.

Try this sample code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

//CREDENTIAL structure
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
#define CRED_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH            513
#define CRED_MAX_CREDENTIAL_BLOB_SIZE       512
#define CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH CRED_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH
#define CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH (CRED_MAX_CREDENTIAL_BLOB_SIZE / 2)


#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    wchar_t pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1] = L"user";
    wchar_t pszPwd[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1]  = L"password";
    BSTR strNetworkResource;
    //To use a WMI remote connection set localconn to false and configure the values of the pszName, pszPwd and the name of the remote machine in strNetworkResource
    bool localconn = true;  
    strNetworkResource = localconn ?  L"\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2" : L"\\\\remote--machine\\root\\CIMV2";

    COAUTHIDENTITY *userAcct =  NULL ;
    COAUTHIDENTITY authIdent;
    HRESULT hres;

    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();          
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------
    if (localconn)
        hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
            NULL,
            -1,                          // COM authentication
            NULL,                        // Authentication services
            NULL,                        // Reserved
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation
            NULL,                        // Authentication info
            EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities
            NULL                         // Reserved
            );
    else
        hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
            NULL,
            -1,                          // COM authentication
            NULL,                        // Authentication services
            NULL,                        // Reserved
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,    // Default Impersonation
            NULL,                        // Authentication info
            EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities
            NULL                         // Reserved
            );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();          
        return 1;                      // Program has failed.
    }

    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. " << "Err code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();              
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\\CIMV2 namespace
    // and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
    if (localconn)  
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
             _bstr_t(strNetworkResource),      // Object path of WMI namespace
             NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
             NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
             0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
             NULL,                    // Security flags.
             0,                       // Authority (e.g. Kerberos)
             0,                       // Context object
             &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
             );
    else
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t(strNetworkResource),  // Object path of WMI namespace
            _bstr_t(pszName),             // User name
            _bstr_t(pszPwd),              // User password
            NULL,                // Locale
            NULL,                // Security flags
            NULL,                // Authority
            NULL,                // Context object
            &pSvc                // IWbemServices proxy
            );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();                  
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to root\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;

    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------
    if (localconn)
        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
           pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
           RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
           RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
           NULL,                        // Server principal name
           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
           RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
           NULL,                        // client identity
           EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities
        );
    else
    {
        // Create COAUTHIDENTITY that can be used for setting security on proxy
        memset(&authIdent, 0, sizeof(COAUTHIDENTITY));
        authIdent.PasswordLength = wcslen (pszPwd);
        authIdent.Password = (USHORT*)pszPwd;
        authIdent.User = (USHORT*)pszName;
        authIdent.UserLength = wcslen(pszName);
        authIdent.Domain = 0;
        authIdent.DomainLength = 0;
        authIdent.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;
        userAcct = &authIdent;

        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
           pSvc,                           // Indicates the proxy to set
           RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
           RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
           COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name
           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
           RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
           userAcct,                       // client identity
           EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities
        );
    }


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();                  
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"Disable");
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Win32_NetworkAdapter");

    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance = NULL;
    hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);



    // Execute Method
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(L"Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID=\"0\"", MethodName, 0,
    NULL, pClassInstance, &pOutParams, NULL);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not execute method. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;        
        SysFreeString(ClassName);
        SysFreeString(MethodName);
        if (pClass) pClass->Release();
        if (pInParamsDefinition) pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        if (pOutParams) pOutParams->Release();
        if (pSvc) pSvc->Release();
        if (pLoc) pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();          
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }


    VARIANT varReturnValue;
    hres = pOutParams->Get(L"ReturnValue", 0, &varReturnValue, NULL, 0);
    if (!FAILED(hres))
    wcout << "ReturnValue " << varReturnValue.intVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&varReturnValue);


    // Clean up    
    SysFreeString(ClassName);
    SysFreeString(MethodName);  
    if (pClass) pClass->Release();
    if (pInParamsDefinition) pInParamsDefinition->Release();
    if (pOutParams) pOutParams->Release();
    if (pLoc) pLoc->Release();
    if (pSvc) pSvc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
    cin.get();  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tryied to execute this code , but it generate an exception at run Time, by debugging the exception is raised by the instruction : `hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);`

Comment: Can you include the error message you are receiving?

Comment: the error is _Exception non gérée à 0x004018d3 dans NetworkToto.exe : 0xC0000005: Violation d'accès lors de la lecture de l'emplacement 0x00000000._ where NetworkToto.exe is the name of the application. this error i think is due to the fact the object `pInParamsDefinition` is NULL.

Comment: If that variable is NULL then there is an error in the line `hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);`  So check the value of `hres` after of that line.

Comment: the value of `hres`is _-2147217406_. what may be the source of that error ?

Comment: This error is related to the current privileges of the user. So try using an admin account or use the option RunAs Admin.

Comment: i tried runing it using the option " RunAs Admin" but it fails also.. meanwhile when trying to execute the methode `create`of the class `WIN32_Process`it is executed succusfully and the object pInParamsDefinition is not NULL... my source code looks as follow :

Comment: `// set up to call the Win32_Process::Create method
    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"Create");
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Win32_Process");

    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0,  &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance = NULL;
    hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);`

Comment: The code above, when run as Administrator, leaves pInParamsDefinition NULL even after the GetMethod() returns HRESULT of S_OK. How can this be? Any ideas? I've no issue getting Disable() to work in PowerShell...

Comment: MSDN claims regarding GetMethod: "Be aware that Windows Management can set the IWbemClassObject pointer to NULL if this method has no in parameters." This is the case with Disable() and Enable(). So, how do we call them instead?

Comment: I ran it without calling GetObject, GetMethod or SpawnInstance. I simply ran ExecMethod with NULL instead of pClassInstance. 

The one problem I had that slowed me down for a day, was that I was using Win32_NetworkAdapter.index instead of Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID. With DeviceID it finally worked. This is odd because if you are calling Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.index, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code RRUZ posted won't work as is because `WIN32_NetworkAdapter`'s `Disable()` (and `Enable()`) methods for have no input parameters. In the call to `ExecMethod()`, you need to pass in a null in place of `pClassInstance` (obviously, don't call `SpawnInstance()` on the null `pInParamsDefinition`). Note, however, that this doesn't necessarily apply to all cases where there seem to be no input parameters; see the discussion at http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.wmi.narkive.com/Pxy4mfTi/calling-method-with-no-input-params-in-c